# There is any technical reason for the new Airbus shades?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus

There is any technical reason for the new Airbus shades? Or they exists just because it is sexy?

[image]

Comment: I voted to reopen because the other question is about glass tint, and (I think) this one is about the frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just for the looks. The A350 is the first Airbus ever to feature curved cocpit windows to reduce drag, and according to Airbus, the black "mask" contributes to ease of maintenance and harmonization of the thermal condition of the windows:

> "The perfectly curved shape of the nose helps the air flow hug the surface, in the least turbulent manner, thereby reducing drag. The emblematic “Ray-Ban” like black windshield eases the window’s maintenance and contributes to harmonising the thermal condition of this temperature-sensitive window area. ..."

[Virgin Atlantic blog - Why does the Airbus A350 wear a Zorro mask?](https://blog.virginatlantic.com/airbus-a350-wear-zorro-mask/://)

Comment: I notice Airbus a321 NEO also has that feature. Does it still have the same purpose as there isn't any noticeable design changes?

Comment: Purely speculative, but I think the black mask on NEO is just a brand gimmick to differentiate it from older versions. To be honest, I think the mask is mostly for cosmetic purposes on A350 too..